# How to prevent SQL injection using a stored procedure while insert record?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005

I am new to SQL Server, I am trying to insert records into table using a stored procedure as shown below.

I want a suggestion that is using the below stored procedure. Also:

- can I prevent SQL injection?
- is it the right way?

Correct me if I miss anything in below procedure which leads to SQL injection.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertParamTable]
   @CmpyCode nvarchar(50),
   @Code nvarchar(50),
   @DisplayCode nvarchar(50),
   @TotalDigit int,
   @Nos bigint,
   @IdentitY int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT tblParamTable (CmpyCode, Code, DisplayCode, TotalDigit, Nos)
   VALUES (@CmpyCode, @Code, @DisplayCode, @TotalDigit, @Nos)
END

SELECT @Identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
RETURN @Identity
```

Comment: As per my knowledge SQL Injection attacks happened from the UI (webpages). In order to prevent the sql injection attacks you need to implement validations for your input fields placed in your web pages.

Comment: @MSRS Unfortunately bad data e.i. SQL inject can come from many places including users, database fields, configuration files. The correct solution is to use parameterised queries, such that strings are never executed directly.

Comment: So long as you're not doing weird things inside your stored procedure like building dynamic SQL and using `EXECUTE` on it, or building a system command that contains user input and running xp_cmdshell with it, your stored procs should be fine.  However, as @rob said, you must call stored proc using parameterized queries; if you build your own `"EXECUTE spInsertParamTable @CmpyCode='"+userInput+...` and execute, then this won't save you as it will be SQLI-able. Be sure to user proper `IDbParameter` to pass parameters into your stored proc.

Comment: Also GRANT execute permissions only so your application level user can only call stored procedures and nothing else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL Injection specifically refers to injecting SQL code into an existing SQL query that's built up via string concatenation and executed dynamically. It is almost always of the form:

```
@dynamicSQL = "select * from sensitivetable where field = " + @injectableParameter
sp_executesql @dynamicSQL
```

For this particular stored procedure, the worst an attacker could do is insert unhelpful values into your *tblParamTable*.

**However**, if these values are then used in a dynamically-built query later on, then this merely becomes a second-order attack: insert values on page 1, see results of dynamic query on page 2. (I only mention this since your table is named tblParamTable, suggesting it might contain parameters for later re-use.)

Answer (score 1):

> Can I prevent SQL injection?

You already are - there is no way to "inject" code into your SQL statement since you're using parameters.

> Is it the right way?

Well, there's not one "right" way - but I don't see anything seriously wrong with what you're doing.  A few *suggestions*:

- You don't need to `RETURN` your output parameter value.  Setting it is enough.
- You have the last `SELECT` outside of the `BEGIN`/`END` block, which isn't *hurting* anything but for consistency you should put everything inside `BEGIN`/`END` (or leave them out altogether).

Comment: Technically this is not correct.  It's about how stored proc is called: if `EXECUTE` command is built by string concatenation with user input (to pass parameters) rather than parameter objects, that the fact that it is a stored proc rather than sql statement is being called will not save from SQLI.